# Список и бесконечный цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x

После добавления значения в список, цикл повторяется, но значение в списке пропадает, как этого избежать?

```
while True:
    lict = list()
    a = input('Добавить юзера в БД? Y/N:')
    if a == 'Y':
        nm = lict.append(input('Введите имя:'))
        print(lict)
    if a == 'N':
       quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вынести объявление списка за цикл?

```
lict = list()
while True:
    a = input('Добавить юзера в БД? Y/N:')
    if a == 'Y':
        nm = lict.append(input('Введите имя:'))
        print(lict)
    if a == 'N':
       quit()
```